# Espresso UI Test Cancelled on Device in android 10

Tags: android, kotlin

- I am create simple ui test case in my app and run default test case.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Test
    fun useAppContext() {
        // Context of the app under test.
        val appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
        assertEquals(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, appContext.packageName)
    }
}
```

**build.gradle.kts**

```
testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

**Dependancies**

```
const val jUnit = "junit:junit:4.13.2"
const val extJUnit = "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2"
const val espresso = "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0"
const val testRules = "com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2"
const val androidXcoreTesting = "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
const val androidcoreTesting = "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1"
const val mockitoCore = "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.0"
const val mockitoAndroid = "org.mockito:mockito-android:2.23.0"
```

Result getting 0 test success
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Update Dependencies:**

```
const val espresso = "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0"
const val jUnit = "junit:junit:4.13.2"
```